# C++ parallelization with Eigen matrices and map iterators

Tags: c++, boost, openmp, eigen, boost-thread

I have a function which calculates the sum of matrices (using the Eigen framework), where the matrices are stored in a std::map. Specifically, I have to do something that looks like this:

```
Eigen::Matrix2f Summer::DoSum(){
  Eigen::Matrix2f sum = Eigen::Matrix2f::Zero();
  BOOST_FOREACH(const auto& myPair,pairMap){
    const Voxel*       voxel = myPair.first;
    const Eigen::Matrix2f& b = myPair.second;
    const float&           a = voxel->GetA();
    sum += a*b;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The map is quite large, so I have considered parallelizing this. There seems to be two main options: openmp and boost. What are the advantages and disadvantages of one over the other in this case? In either case, would the code require significant rewriting? From what I can see, the openmp implementation of this example is not straightforward.

Comment: Why is the openmp not straightforward? You need a `#pragma omp parallel for` and a mutex around `sum`.

Comment: I was under the impression that `#pragma omp parallel for` could only be used for random-access iterators in parallel loops

Comment: Ohh I think you're right, it looks like the iterators need to be random. But then why do you store the matrices in a `map`? Cannot you use a `vector` instead?

Comment: @vsoftco I need the key look-up functionality of maps elsewhere in the code. I could copy to a vector, but at a first glance this seems like overkill.

Comment: What's the order of magnitude of the matrices M*N and of the the map's size?

Comment: @decltype_auto The matrices will be 2*2 for now, but this may increase to 4*4 (but no more). The map size is arbitraryish, currently it is 100-300, but in future it may be a factor of 10 larger. This sum needs to be calculated for approximately 10^6 maps, and the entire process (the sum calculated for each map) will be repeated approximately 10^3 times.

Comment: @kd88 What about MPI for that?

Comment: @vsoftco instead of a mutex (mutexes in openmp?!) use a reduction

Comment: @sehe Good point! I was thinking of a mutex in the general sense, like protecting each write to `sum`.

Comment: @vsoftco That would be a critical section :) Reductions abstract it further, which is heaps better in the case of operator+

Comment: @sehe I thought that reduction only supported native types

Comment: @kd88 you could be right. Even then, task-local sums and a critical-section/barrier would be more openmp